# Orange in timeline, playblack won't go to frame 1

Tags: timeline

I've accidentally set some markers in my scene, and now Blender has locked on to a section of my scene. How can I remove the markers?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I immediately solved it right after I posted. I unchecked this little box and it went away.

[image]

Comment: the shortcuts to define a new range and cancel it are P and Alt P, maybe you've pressed P by mistake